# Facebook like button bug on page load

Tags: facebook, button, share, facebook-like

I have an irritating bug with the Facebook like button.  When my page is loading, my share buttons (Facebook like, Tweet, +1 buttons) will start on the left side.  **Then they will appear in the middle of the page.**  And finally when the loading is finished, they will appear in the correct position on the left side again.

The shifting of the share buttons all over the page is kind of annoying and looks unprofessional, even though they end up at the correct position on the left side when the page is done loading.

I believe this is related to the Facebook like button.  I have tested this in IE and Chrome in Windows.  I have also tested this in Safari on IPhone.  All browsers seem to have the same problem.

You can see the bug here:

http://www.alphabanter.com/

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  Looks like **width=450** was causing the problem.  I removed **width=450** and the Like button now stays on the left side of the page and does not jump around anymore.  Maybe there is a deeper reason why **width=450** causes problems for my page but at least it works now.